# How To Fix WPF XAML Border Clip Masking In Design Preview?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, border

- **Problem:**

After updating a few WPF projects in C# using Visual Studio to a higher target framework such as .NET 4.7, I noticed that wherever I used a Border.Clip in my xaml code, it would "mask" and hide everything in the design preview. All compiles and runs just fine but when working on the code in XAML, it is hard to see any visual feedback with code changes since the clip "masks" everything when before in older .NET frameworks, I never had this issue. Can someone explain why this is happening and what a solution may be?

Here is an example of what I see in a xaml file when I add a Border.Clip (Again, a complied version will show the real elements, it only appears this way in the preview in Visual Studio)

[Border.Clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgeaf.png)

`

```
        <Border.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                   ...Some binding for dimensions.
                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
            </RectangleGeometry>
        </Border.Clip>
```

`
Omitting this code, will reveal all UI elements in the preview.

Again, the code is correct and does its job on runtime. With that said, I've tried both omitting and being super specific about any radius, shape, or dimensions of the clip and both still "mask" the preview.

For example just adding this line of code, masks everything.

`

```
        <Border.Clip>
        </Border.Clip>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

As you could see I didn't have your problem.

My test environment is in `VS 2022 Community 17.4.1` `.Net Framework 4.8`.

Maybe there is a little problem with your usage, please refer to the following [documents.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip?view=winrt-22621)

[image]

[image]

My demo code:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Image Source="Your path" Height="150" Canvas.Left="148" Canvas.Top="67">
            <Image.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="100 75 50 50"/>
            </Image.Clip>
        </Image>
        <Border Background="Chocolate" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Width="300" Height="250" Canvas.Left="387" Canvas.Top="67">
            <Border.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="100 75 50 50"/>
            </Border.Clip>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```